Creating generics with delegate protocol type
I am trying to refactor this code:
@objc protocol BaseDelegate {
    func xxx()
}

protocol DerivedDelegate: BaseDelegate {
    func yyy()
}

protocol NextDerivedDelegate: BaseDelegate {
    func zzz()
}

class BaseClass<T> {
    var delegate: T?
}

class DerivedClass: BaseClass<DerivedDelegate> {
     ....
}

class NextDerivedClass: BaseClass<NextDerivedDelegate> {
     ....
}

As you can already tell, there is a memory leak here, among other things that can go wrong. So I am trying to refactor it but to no avail. This is what I currently have:
@objc protocol BaseDelegate: AnyObject {
    func xxx()
}

protocol DerivedDelegate: BaseDelegate {
    func yyy()
}

protocol NextDerivedDelegate: BaseDelegate {
    func zzz()
}

class BaseClass<T: BaseDelegate> {
    weak var delegate: T?
}

class DerivedClass: BaseClass<DerivedDelegate> {
     ....
}

class NextDerivedClass: BaseClass<NextDerivedDelegate> {
     ....
}

But when I was tried building it, it returned this error:

Type 'any DerivedDelegate' cannot conform to 'BaseDelegate'

Even when I tried class DerivedClass: BaseClass<BaseDelegate> it returned Type 'any BaseDelegate' cannot conform to 'BaseDelegate'. Is there any way to fix this? There are a lot of these classes and delegates so changing them one by one and removing the generics should be the last thing to do if there is any other solution.
Thank you.

Why class BaseClass<T: BaseDelegate>? You didn't constraint T in the first code snippet.

@Sweeper To make sure that it should only be used for that delegate protocol and its derivation. Which is what T is being used as in the whole project. The first code is the existing legacy code and not mine. I am just being hired to fix it (and the rest of the code). I can refactor to not use generics but it will take a lot of efforts since I have to search and change hundreds of classes.

Swift protocols cannot conform to other protocols, but Objective-C protocols can.
The code compiles if all three protocols are @objc.
@objc 
protocol BaseDelegate: AnyObject {
    func xxx()
}

@objc
protocol DerivedDelegate: BaseDelegate {
    func yyy()
}

@objc
protocol NextDerivedDelegate: BaseDelegate {
    func zzz()
}


Thanks. This works. However, this creates another new set of errors. Because some of the functions have parameters that can't be represented in objc. But at least it does work. Thanks again.
